# Can I create another portal home from the end after I've lost mine?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was in creative mode and I killed the ender dragon. I then broke every portal block so I could collect the dragon egg. I forgot I could cover them, and now I can't escape the end without dieing. Can I create another portal home?

Answer (score -13, accepted):

You could just note down the items that you have got then kill yourself. Then, because you are in creative mode, you can give yourself the same items that you had before you died.

Just don't ever go back to the End.

Comment: This doesn't address the question asked.  The question asks "Can I create a portal home" not "How do I recover my items?"

Comment: @Retrosaur And yet this is the accepted answer...I'm really lost as to what to do.

Comment: Yeah, we can' t really do anything. It's up to asker I guess.

Comment: @Retrosaur We can always fix terrible grammar.

Answer (score 17):

Short answer: **NO.**

Once you break your portal blocks, there's no going back, unless you spawn another enderdragon (to spawn a portal upon death), place the necessary blocks yourself (via TMI (aka Too Many Items)), but no other solutions. Note, nether portals also do not work here, as they cannot take you back as well.

Unless you plan to use external 3rd party programs, as fredley mentioned, you cannot create a portal home.

Comment: How do I spawn another enderdragon?

Comment: Sadly, you'll have to use a mod to help you with that.  There are no existing options to spawn entities within Minecraft (vanilla)

Comment: Via too much information?

Comment: TMI stands for TooManyItems, a common mod for Minecraft.

Comment: In Minecraft 1.7 (soon to be released), with cheats you will be able to summon the enderdragon with the summon entity command.

Answer (score 13):

Long answer: **YES**

What you will need to do is use [MCEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-now-open-source/) to place a new End Portal.

[Here is a schematic.](http://www.planetminecraft.com/project/end-portal-mcedit-schematic/) You'll need to import it with MCEdit and place it, and it should allow you to leave the End.

Comment: fredley I get a "url not found" error when I follow that link.

Comment: @John I've updated the link.

Answer (score 2):

If you have cheat mode enabled you can `/give <yourself> 119` which is the end portal which will transport you back to your spawn point in the overworld

Comment: Thanks! That's really helppful! Unfortunately, that's how I got TO  the end and I tried using it to get out but the portal blocks despawn instantly when placed.........

Comment: This no longer works as of 1.7

Answer (score 1):

In the newest snapshot ,as of xmas 2013, simply go into the End and do /summon Enderdragon and kill it, the press Esc during the credits.

Answer (score -1):

If you are in creative, just die by jumping off the end and give your items once back in the overworld.

Comment: How does this answer differ from the accepted answer? (the one with `-11` points)